# Битрикс дважды выполняет AJAX запрос

Tags: битрикс

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть магазин на 1С-Битрикс, для него написал оформление заказа на Vue, так же сделал небольшое API для работы.
Немного кода API (код API упрощен):

```
<?php
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$result['order'] = Orders::registerOrder($input['basketItems'], $input['props'], $input['prices'], $userId, false);
echo json_encode($result);
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php");
?>
```

Проблема в том, что из приложения Vue отправляется запрос (отправляется один раз) на регистрацию заказа и заказ регистрируется дважды (первый заказ пустой, второй нормальный). При этом, если отдельно запустить функцию Orders::registerOrder(), то заказ регистрируется один раз и все с ним нормально. Не могу понять в какую сторону копать. Эту проблему встречаю уже не первый раз, но решения для нее найти не могу. Либо это какое-то кэширование битрикса, либо, возможно, настройки сервера какие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это CORS.

Стандарт Cross-Origin Resource Sharing работает с помощью добавления новых HTTP-заголовков, которые позволяют серверам описывать набор источников, которым разрешено читать информацию, запрашиваемую web-браузером. В частности, для методов HTTP-запросов, которые могут привести к побочным эффектам над данными сервера (в частности, для HTTP методов, отличных от GET или для POST запросов, использующих определнные MIME-типы), спецификация требует, чтобы браузеры "предпроверяли" запрос, запрашивая поддерживающие методы с сервера с помощью метода HTTP-запроса OPTIONS и затем, поверх "подтверждения" с сервера, отсылали фактический запрос с фактическим методом HTTP-запроса. Сервера также могут оповещать клиентов должны ли "полномочия" (включая Cookies и HTTP Authentication данные) быть отправлены с запросом.

Пустой запрос это `options`
Подробнее [тут](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) либо [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Спасибо, ответ помог, проблему решил!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог то можете пометить как полезный